# How do I get the current limits of a matplotlib axis?

Tags: matplotlib, range, axes

Given a `matplotlib` axis, how do I find its current min and max limits; e.g., as might have been previously set in `ax.set(xscale='log', xlim=...)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()`

`ymin,ymax = ax.get_ylim()`